# What if I implement !Unpin for a type which also implements DerefMut?

Tags: rust

I know the priciple of `Pin` is not to expose mutable reference of its inner type. If I want to actually pin a type, I need to implement `!Unpin` for it.

While doing some research, I know I can create a `!Unpin` object by `Pin::new_unchecked`. However, I need to make sure we can not move in `P::Deref/DerefMut`. What if I both implement `!Unpin` and a `DerefMut` that actually move inner fields? Will it make `Pin` no longer taking effects?

So I write the following code. It defines a `EvilNUnpin` which it a pointer to String which do evil things. It actually mutates the String `b` by setting it to `3`.

What I expect is by calling `std::mem::swap`

1. `xp.deref()` and `xp2.deref()` will equal to 3, since we have called `DerefMut`.
2. If we save the pointer of String `x1.b` and `x2.b` before we wrapped it into a Pin. I think we should finally observe the value of `ptr1` and `ptr2` is finally 3. However, it is not. I wonder why.

```
#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct EvilNUnpin {
    b: String,
}
impl !Unpin for EvilNUnpin {}

impl Deref for EvilNUnpin {
    type Target = String;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.b
    }
}

impl DerefMut for EvilNUnpin {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        self.b = "3".to_owned();
        &mut self.b
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x1 = EvilNUnpin { b: "1".to_owned() };
    let mut x2 = EvilNUnpin { b: "2".to_owned() };
    let ptr1 = &x1.b as *const _ as isize;
    let ptr2 = &x2.b as *const _ as isize;
    // Note that we consider x1 and x2 as a pointer, so we don't use &x1
    let mut xp = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(x1) };
    let mut xp2 = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(x2) };
    std::mem::swap(&mut xp.as_mut(), &mut xp2.as_mut());
    assert_eq!(xp.deref(), "3");
    assert_eq!(xp2.deref(), "3");
    unsafe {
        let n1 = &*(ptr1 as *const String);
        let n2 = &*(ptr2 as *const String);
        assert_eq!(n1, "3"); // fire, actually 1
        assert_eq!(n2, "3"); // fire, actually 2
    }
}
```

Maybe it is because there are actually some copy here?

**EDIT**

I have changed my implementation, and make sure the inner String is not moved. What I want to check is what will happen if I break the constraint of `Pin::new_unchecked`. I think `!Unpin` will not take effect, so we will end up with the two value swapped. However, it is still not correct.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct EvilNUnpin<'a> {
    b: &'a mut String,
}
impl !Unpin for EvilNUnpin<'_> {}

impl Deref for EvilNUnpin<'_> {
    type Target = String;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.b
    }
}

impl DerefMut for EvilNUnpin<'_> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        self.b.push('a');
        &mut self.b
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s1 = "1".to_owned();
    let mut s2 = "2".to_owned();
    let ptr1 = &s1 as *const _ as isize;
    let ptr2 = &s2 as *const _ as isize;
    let mut x1 = EvilNUnpin { b: &mut s1 };
    let mut x2 = EvilNUnpin { b: &mut s2 };
    // Note that we don't use a reference.
    let mut xp = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(x1) };
    let mut xp2 = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(x2) };
    std::mem::swap(&mut xp.as_mut(), &mut xp2.as_mut());
    unsafe {
        let n1 = &*(ptr1 as *const String);
        let n2 = &*(ptr2 as *const String);
        assert_eq!(n1, "1a"); // why not 2a
        assert_eq!(n2, "2a"); // why not 1a
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation on `Pin::as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.as_mut) (emphasis mine):

> This is a generic method to go from `&mut Pin<Pointer<T>>` to `Pin<&mut T>`. It is safe because, as part of the contract of `Pin::new_unchecked`, the pointee cannot move after `Pin<Pointer<T>>` got created. **“Malicious” implementations of `Pointer::DerefMut` are likewise ruled out by the contract of `Pin::new_unchecked`.**

And for `Pin::new_unchecked` [we see this:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.new_unchecked)

> This constructor is unsafe because we cannot guarantee that the data pointed to by pointer is pinned, meaning that the data will not be moved or its storage invalidated until it gets dropped. **If the constructed `Pin<P>` does not guarantee that the data `P` points to is pinned, that is a violation of the API contract and may lead to undefined behavior in later (safe) operations.**
>
> By using this method, you are making a promise about the `P::Deref` and `P::DerefMut` implementations, if they exist. Most importantly, **they must not move out of their self arguments**: `Pin::as_mut` and `Pin::as_ref` will call `DerefMut::deref_mut` and `Deref::deref` on the pinned pointer and expect these methods to uphold the pinning invariants.

And your implementation clearly moves the value inside `DerefMut` - it drops this value, to be precise.

So, it's assumed that `EvilNUnpin` is simply unsound to ever be pinned; in other words, `Pin::new_unchecked` is to blame for the output you see.

Comment: Hi, What I actually want to check is what will happen it we implemented `!Unpin` and a malicious `DerefMut`. I think by our malicious `DerefMut`, `Pin` can no longer hide `&mut` from us, so we can get the two value swapped. However, after I removed the drop problem be introducing references, what I expect still not happen.

Comment: Seems it is an exchange between `&mut String` and `&mut String`

Comment: Sorry, I seem to misunderstand the question. Why did you expect `swap`ping two `Pin<&mut T>`s to do something with `T`s, then?

Comment: Well, this is my current understanding. If we swap two `Box<T>::as_mut()`, we can actually  swap the two `T`s. However, in my question, I actually swap two `Pin<EvilNUnpin>`, which is something like `Pin<&String>` which is actualy "a pointer to a pointer", so I am actually swapping two pointers?

Comment: `Pin::as_mut` returns `Pin<&mut T>`, therefore `&mut Pin::as_mut` is `&mut Pin<&mut T>`, and the thing being swapped is `Pin`, not `T`.

Comment: Yes, but swap two `&mut Box<&T>` can actually swap `T` themselves. See [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rzn763wzV7/).

Comment: In playground this assertion fails - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bdfbcb4175b9e5b097944431b3982d13.

Comment: OK, I get it, The difference between `&x1` and `x1` is subtle but significant.